# Microsoft Access 2016 Round

Tags: ms-access

Im using Microsoft Access 2016 to try to round a number but I get an error.
Do I need to set a reference to something

Error:

Compile Error:

Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

```
Dim Amount As Double
Dim Result As Double

Amount = 210.67
Result = Round(Amount, 0)

Debug.Print Result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you somewhere have a custom function `Round` not taking two arguments, ie.:

```
Public Function Round(Value As Double) As Double
```

If so, modify your code to specifically use `Round` of `VBA`:

```
Result = VBA.Round(Amount, 0)
```

and it will compile.

That said, VBA's Round is quite buggy. For serious and/or extreme rounding, use the rounding functions from my library at **GitHub**: [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round).

**Addendum: Round up**

My generic function `RoundUp` found in module [RoundingMethods.bas](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round/blob/master/RoundingMethods.bas) will do that. In your case, simply use:

```
Result = -Int(-Amount)
```

Comment: Thanks I had not herd of VBA.Round before.
All the examples I see just show Round.

It turns out what im wanting to do is RoundUp.
Don’t think Access supports that - But let me know if this is possible in Access.

So im using Int
Result = Int(YourValue) + 1
Result = Int(2.1) + 1 = 3